# how to detect HANA studio environment?

Tags: sapui5, hana, hana-xs, hana-studio

I have an sapui5 code on HANA studio and would like to know how I can programatically tell if I'm in Dev, test or Prod environment. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could check the application URL with window.location and use it  to determine the environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system view `M_DATABASE` as documented [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20ae63aa7519101496f6b832ec86afbd.html).

In column `USAGE` you can find whether the system is used for production, test, development, demo, ...

SAP HANA Studio uses this information to set the UI colour differently for production systems and to provide additional confirmation dialogues when changing data.